# in Java array even average, I am having problem in return

Tags: java, arrays

The question is if the number in an array is even then we've to print the sum of even numbers and then return the average. Here I am getting the sum but my average is not returning.

```
public static double evenAverage(ARRAY arr[]) {
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].num % 2 == 0) {
            sum = sum + arr[i].num;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        avg = sum/count;
}
    System.out.println("even sum is: " +sum);
    System.out.println("average is: ");
    return  avg;
}
```

Comment: It >is< returning.  But it won't print ... because the second `println` statement doesn't include `avg` in the string it is printing.  Look at the line before it .....

Comment: Having said that, your 2nd for loop is unnecessary.  You only need to compute the average once.  Not repeatedly.  I think your real problem is that you are not **reading** the code that you have written.

Comment: I suggest that you read about [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/).  Seriously.  The key to debugging is learning to read your own code accurately, and RDD is a way to learn to do this.

Comment: I have not used +avg in the second printing line because in the question they've asked me to print the sum and then return the average. Not to print the average. Now if I use +avg in the printing line, wouldn't it be wrong as per the question requirement? I am just a beginner so really confused about this.

Comment: If you actually mean that you are not returning the average, I think you are wrong.  You are returning the average!  Maybe you should look at where you are calling this method.  (But note that you are computing the average of the even numbers, not the average of all of the numbers.  I can't tell what you were actually asked to do.   And there is a subtle bug if the array contains NO even numbers.)

Comment: okay i got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you looping over arr[]

```
 for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   avg = sum/count;
}
```

average can be calculated directly as you have both sum and count.

```
avg = sum/count;
```

Moreover, 2nd println statement does not print avg.
rest it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code but I have some tips:

1. The second for loop you have is unnecessary since to calculate the average you only need to do this calculation once

```
avg = sum/count;
```

2. The avg variable is being returned correctly you just need to add it in the print statementas you did with the sum variable so you can see it in the console.